# "RectAreaLightHelper" Not Moving in React-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, lighting, react-three-fiber

**Briefing:**
It seems that all of the other light helpers work by showing me the position and rotation on the screen. I understand the rectAreaLight only works on specific materials and is now located in the "three/examples" folder. I'm calling it with the "useHelper" function and that it doesn't move when I change the position arguments.

**Codepen:** [simple scene](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-framework-3holn?file=/src/App.js)

*Code Description*: "moon.gltf" model, a background, rectAreaLight, Helper, boilerplate. **RectAreaLightHelper is stuck as position [0,0,0].**

**Troubleshooting:**
I'm using the "react-three-gui" library, upon removing the features, the "RectLightHelper" still doesn't move in the scene.

=========================================

**QUESTION**: How do I set up the "RectAreaLightHelper" properly within a "react-three-fiber" scene?

=========================================

Any info or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I'm having the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

It seems to work when I fall back onto THREE syntax. You can then put   `<RectArealightWithHelper>` on your `<Canvas>` as you would any other component in @react-three/fiber.

```
const RectArealightWithHelper = () => {

  const { scene } = useThree();

  RectAreaLightUniformsLib.init();

  const rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight("red", 5, 4, 10);

  rectLight.position.set([-5, 5, 5);
  scene.add(rectLight);
  scene.add(new RectAreaLightHelper(rectLight));

  return null;
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-rectarealighthelper-demo-cd3rw?file=/src/App.js:403-1011)

Besides the useThree hook, all of this is taken straight from one of the
examples on threejs.org: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_rectarealight.

---

See comment in the Codesandbox for research and **bug report**.